# How to capture data inside dropdown using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/cash/bill/PostingBillTypeCombo',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                name: "BillTypeId",
                required: true,
                currencyId: selectedCurrencyId
            },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                ------
                -----
                
                }

            },
        });
```

[image]

how can i capture data inside `function (data)`  the above image is the data which is send to function (data).

i need to capture the Debit inside the function(data).

Should i stringfy and capture it or is there another way of doing it?

Should i capture it using option value or is there another way of doing it?

Im a beginner so help me out on this.This is for my school project

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value to a variable then transfer using ajax. You need to stringify only if it's an array or object.

```
var option_value = $("#BillTypeId option:selected"); 
$.ajax({
            url: '/cash/bill/PostingBillTypeCombo',
            data: {result: option_value},
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                ------
                -----
                
                }

            },
     });
```

In server side if you are using php you can get the value by using this method

> $option_value = $_POST['result'];

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are using it with jQuery, I have created a Sample for you.

As you are getting your  as a string in data, you can create a dummy template and access the element with CSS selector.

Try with below code:

```
var txt="<select><option value ='1000'>DEBIT</option><option value ='9999'> Credit</option></select>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, 'text/html');
 

$(htmlDoc).find('option:contains("DEBIT")').val()
```

//OutPut:"1000"